# MYSQL Query Fill Gaps with Data with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am querying a MYSQL database which has a table named PRICE with the following fields: user, price_date, morning, afternoon. I am grabbing all the morning prices for the current week for the current user to be used as an array in a JS.Charts line chart. The issue I am having is that there may be missing days so the array that I am creating from the query is creating date gaps in the chart.

I created another table named calendar with three fields: datefield, morning, afternoon. I filled it with this years dates (YYYY-MM-DD) along with 0's for the morning and afternoon values.

I now have been trying to write a LEFT JOIN query to select all morning values for the current week and join it with the second table to fill in the date gaps with zeros but I can not get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.morning, c.morning 
        FROM price p 
        LEFT JOIN calendar c ON p.price_date = c.datefield 
        WHERE p.user = '$user' AND YEARWEEK(p.price_date) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
        ORDER BY p.price_date";
```

The data being used and what is being outputted:

Table Price:

| user | price_date | morning | afternoon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lpepper | 2021-03-15 | 23 | 35 |
| lpepper | 2021-03-17 | 43 | 52 |
| lpepper | 2021-03-18 | 24 | 35 |
| lpepper | 2021-03-19 | 78 | 85 |

Table Calendar (Partial - goes for whole year)

| datefield | morning | afternoon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-16 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-17 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-18 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-19 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-20 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-21 | 0 | 0 |

I need the query to return the morning prices for this week (M to SUN) with zeros filled in for the missing dates:

Array should be: 23,0,43,24,78,0,0

My query above returns: ,0,0,0

To make the array I am doing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $morning = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        $morning[] = $row["morning"]; 
    }
```

Then when used in the graph:

```
<?php echo implode(", ", $morning); ?>
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` will put values from your `calendar` table next to those of `price`, if there is a match. You seem to want the opposite to happen, so you would need to use `RIGHT JOIN`, or `FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN price p`

Comment: Tried RIGHT JOIN and did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `LEFT JOIN`, the table with all the rows that should be in the output should be first.

If you have conditions on the other table, you need to put them in the `ON` clause. If there's no match to `c.datefield`, you'll get `NULL` for the `p` columns, and testing them in `WHERE` will filter those rows out.

The date should be filtered from the `calendar` table, not `price`. And you should return the date so you know what the rows are for.

Give aliases to `p.morning` and `c.morning` so you can distinguish them when getting the columns from the results.

You should order by the column in `c`, since `p.price_date` will be `NULL` for the missing dates.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.datefield, IFNULL(p.morning, 0) AS price_morning, c.morning AS cal_morning
        FROM calendar c
        LEFT JOIN price p ON p.price_date = c.datefield 
            AND p.user = '$user'
        WHERE YEARWEEK(c.datefield) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
        ORDER BY c.datefield";
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pTL8tB9pCijVY3r8CAFfkY/0)

On an unrelated note, you should use a prepared statement rather than substituting a variable into the SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the help but this did not work - still does not fill in the gaps. I did try with the tables reversed earlier and I could not get it to work.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: This query returned all zeros and not filtered by the where - the array ended up being all zeros for very line in the CALENDAR table - not a joined result for just this week.

Comment: Tried: `$sql = "SELECT p.morning, c.morning FROM calendar c WHERE YEARWEEK(c.datefield) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) LEFT JOIN price p ON p.price_date = c.datefield AND p.user = '$user' AND YEARWEEK(p.price_date) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) ORDER BY c.datefield";` It returns: ,0,0,0

Comment: You can't put `WHERE` before `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I've updated the answer and made a db-fiddle demo.

Comment: I tried and it returns: 0, 43, 24, 78, 0 using price_morning to create the array.The correct return needs to be 23, 0, 43, 24, 78, 0, 0. If I add any of the modes to the YEARWEEK as in `WHERE YEARWEEK(c.datefield, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)` it returns: 0, 43, 24, 78, 0, 0

Comment: This worked - had an issue with creating the array - now works thank you for your help. Creating the array as follows: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $morning = array(); 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $morning[] = $row["price_morning"]; 
 }`